# fullCalendar multiple function eventSources

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use fullCalendar with multiple event sources and using functions in order to get the events. The piece of code below is a try but it seems to forget my first source and only the events from the second source are displayed.
What's wrong and How can I fix that?

```
eventSources:[{
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            console.log("events: "+start + "/" + end);
            $('.fc-sun').css('color', "#ff0000");


            var jsonstate = jQuery("#jsonstate").attr("value");
            if (jsonstate != ""){
                var events = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonstate).events;


                callback(events);

            }
            return events;
        }
    },
    {
        events: function(start, end, callback) {
            console.log("ferie: "+start + "/" + end);

            $('.fc-sun').css('color', "#ff0000");


            var jsonfeste = jQuery("#jsonfeste").attr("value");
            if (jsonfeste != ""){
                var feste = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonfeste).events;


                callback(feste);

            }
            return feste;
        }
    }
    ],
```